# Referential integrity between tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have 2 tables, `Members` and `Enrollments`. Both tables can be joined using primary key `Member ID`.

I need to write a query which returns all the members in the `Members` table which don't have a corresponding row in the `Enrollments` table and vice versa.

This is what I have so far:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#memberswithoutenrollments') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #memberswithoutenrollments 

SELECT m.* 
INTO #memberswithoutenrollments 
FROM ABC_Members m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC_MemEnrollment e ON m.MemberID = MemberID
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, but rather put the actual data in the question.

Comment: Your syntax strongly suggests that you are using sql server and not mysql.

Comment: Pretty sure that all you need is a where clause. Where e.MemberID IS NULL

Comment: SELECT m.* 
INTO #memberswithoutenrollments 
FROM ABC_Members m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC_MemEnrollment e ON m.MemberID = MemberID where isnull(e.memberid,'')=''

Comment: if you have enrollments without members, than you have not setup foreign keys. Do yourself a favor and setup foreign keys once you have all the corrupt rows removed, than you will never ever have to do this again

Comment: Thank you for the input. Actually Im testing the data for inaccuracies and hence this question came up

Answer (score 1):

`FULL JOIN` is a simple method for comparing lists between two tables:

```
SELECT COALESCE(e.MemberID, m.MemberID),
       (CASE WHEN e.MemberID IS NULL THEN 'No Enrollments' ELSE 'No Member' END)
FROM ABC_Members m FULL JOIN
     ABC_MemEnrollment e
     ON m.MemberID = e.MemberID
WHERE e.MemberID IS NULL OR m.MemberID IS NULL;
```

But if you have proper foreign key relationships, then you should never have enrollments without members.

Comment: thank you Gordon, I agree with your point that there should be no enrollments without members

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` to your benefit here.

```
WITH
    -- Create a list of all of the matches
    in_table AS
        (
            SELECT
                Member_ID
            FROM
                Enrollments
            WHERE
                Members.MemberID = Enrollments.Member_ID
        ),

    result_table AS
        (
            SELECT
                *

            FROM
                Members

            -- Grab only the values from members that DO NOT APPEAR in in_table
            WHERE
                MemberID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT FROM in_table)
        )

-- Grab all results
SELECT * FROM result_table
```